# What's the purpose of the UD2 opcode in the Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, assembly, linux-kernel

I have found the following fragment in the Linux kernel (not the corresponding C code though), somewhere during the start up phase. You can clearly see the `0F 0B` parts, which stand for the [UD2](http://siyobik.info.gf/main/reference/instruction/UD2) opcode (IDA refused to disassemble).

There are some possible usages for this opcode explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7268558/1078067) and [here](http://lwn.net/Articles/255364/). In this case, however, the opcodes after this instruction don't really make sense.

```
seg000:000C059E                 test    edx, edx
seg000:000C05A0                 jnz     short loc_C05AA
seg000:000C05A0 ; --------------------------------------------------
seg000:000C05A2                 db  0Fh
seg000:000C05A3                 db  0Bh
seg000:000C05A4                 db 73h
seg000:000C05A5                 db 0
seg000:000C05A6                 db  86h ; å
seg000:000C05A7                 db  4Ah ; J
seg000:000C05A8                 db  27h ; '
seg000:000C05A9                 db 0C0h ; +
seg000:000C05AA ; --------------------------------------------------
seg000:000C05AA
seg000:000C05AA loc_C05AA:                              
seg000:000C05AA                 cmp     eax, [edi+4]
seg000:000C05AD                 jbe     short loc_C05B7
seg000:000C05AD ; --------------------------------------------------
seg000:000C05AF                 db  0Fh
seg000:000C05B0                 db  0Bh
seg000:000C05B1                 db 75h
seg000:000C05B2                 db    0
seg000:000C05B3                 db 86h
seg000:000C05B4                 db  4Ah ; J
seg000:000C05B5                 db  27h ; '
seg000:000C05B6                 db 0C0h ; +
seg000:000C05B7 ; --------------------------------------------------
seg000:000C05B7
seg000:000C05B7 loc_C05B7:                              
seg000:000C05B7                 add     ecx, 0FFFh
seg000:000C05BD                 shr     esi, 0Ch
seg000:000C05C0                 shr     ecx, 0Ch
seg000:000C05C3                 sub     ecx, esi
seg000:000C05C5                 cmp     ecx, ebx
seg000:000C05C7                 jnb     short loc_C05E9
seg000:000C05C9                 lea     esi, [esi+0]
seg000:000C05D0
seg000:000C05D0 loc_C05D0:                              
seg000:000C05D0                 mov     edx, [edi+8]
seg000:000C05D3                 btr     [edx], ecx
seg000:000C05D6                 sbb     eax, eax
seg000:000C05D8                 test    eax, eax
seg000:000C05DA                 jnz     short loc_C05E4
seg000:000C05DA ; ------------------------------------------------
seg000:000C05DC                 db  0Fh
seg000:000C05DD                 db  0Bh
seg000:000C05DE                 db 7Fh
seg000:000C05DF                 db 0
seg000:000C05E0                 db  86h ; å
seg000:000C05E1                 db  4Ah ; J
seg000:000C05E2                 db  27h ; '
seg000:000C05E3                 db 0C0h ; +
seg000:000C05E4 ; -------------------------------------------------
seg000:000C05E4
seg000:000C05E4 loc_C05E4:                              
seg000:000C05E4                 inc     ecx
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's the BUG() macro from [include/asm-i386/bug.h](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/include/asm-i386/bug.h?h=v2.6.13).

```
/*
 * Tell the user there is some problem.
 * The offending file and line are encoded after the "officially
 * undefined" opcode for parsing in the trap handler.
 */

#ifdef CONFIG_DEBUG_BUGVERBOSE
#define BUG()                           \
 __asm__ __volatile__(  "ud2\n"         \
                        "\t.word %c0\n" \
                        "\t.long %c1\n" \
                         : : "i" (__LINE__), "i" (__FILE__))
```

For example, the one at 0C05AF is for file with name at 0xC0274A86 and line number 117 (0x75).