# Why does Clang generate ud2 opcode on OSX?

Tags: macos, assembly, clang

This is possibly similar to a question here: [What's the purpose of the UD2 opcode in the Linux kernel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11140136/whats-the-purpose-of-the-ud2-opcode-in-the-linux-kernel), however, I'm getting this on OSX not on linux, and wouldn't know where to look to see if it is the same as the BUG() macro mentioned there.

I've been getting a number of release build only crashes on my OSX build which are to do with the ud2 opcode and was wondering what would cause clang to generate them.  Here is an example:

```
COMMON_UI::BackProject3DPosition(UTILITYLIB::TVECTOR<float, 3u> const&, UTILITYLIB::TVECTOR<float, 3u> const&) const:
0x1e0705c:  pushl  %ebp
0x1e0705d:  movl   %esp, %ebp
0x1e0705f:  ud2    
0x1e07061:  nop
```

This only happens at -O2, and not -O1, so it looks like the optimisations are going slighty awry.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question is much more suited to the [Clang developer's mailing list](http://lists.cs.uiuc.edu/mailman/listinfo/cfe-dev) or the [LLVM bugtracker](http://llvm.org/bugs/) than Stackoverflow. That being said, try to reduce your code to a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), and post that to the mailing list or bugtracker. Then the people that can fix this will have all they need to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure about `clang`, but `gcc` sometimes inserts `ud2` to mark code areas which exhibit undefined behavior and thus are not supposed to be executed. It does give a warning in such cases, however.

So I suspect there are some warning from the compiler which you are ignoring or suppressing. Try adding `-Wall -Werror` to the command line.

Comment: I fixed one such problem by fixing a warning.  I'll have a fresh warnings sweep and see if the other issues go away.